# Empty variables parsing TLE file

Tags: python, database, parsing

I am trying to parse a TLE file, knowing that it is composed as follows: (source: https://www.space-track.org/documentation#tle) and it turns out that the variables **satellite_catalog_number, epoch_year, epoch_day, first_derivative_mean_motion, second_derivative_mean_motion, bstar, element_set_number, inclination, mean_anomaly, mean_motion** are empty.

I tried this:

```
import requests
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Float, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

class Satellite:
    def __init__(self, name, line1, line2, line3):
        self.name = name
        self.line1 = line1
        self.line2 = line2
        self.line3 = line3
        self.satellite_catalog_number = self.parse_int(line1[2:7])  # Satellite Catalog Number
        self.classification = line1[7]  # Classification
        self.international_designator = line1[9:17]  # International Designator (Launch Year and Number)
        self.epoch_year = self.parse_int(line1[18:20])  # Epoch Year (Last two digits of the launch year)
        self.epoch_day = self.parse_float(line1[20:32])  # Epoch Day (Fractional portion of the Julian day)
        self.first_derivative_mean_motion = self.parse_float(line1[33:43])  # First Derivative of the Mean Motion
        self.second_derivative_mean_motion = self.parse_float(line1[44:52])  # Second Derivative of the Mean Motion
        self.bstar = self.parse_float(line1[53:61])  # B* Drag Term
        self.element_set_number = self.parse_int(line1[64:68])  # Element Set Number

        self.inclination = self.parse_float(line2[8:16])  # Inclination (Inclinación en grados)
        self.raan = self.parse_float(line2[17:25])  # RAAN (Right Ascension of the Ascending Node) en grados
        self.eccentricity = self.parse_float(f"0.{line2[26:33]}")  # Eccentricity (Excentricidad)
        self.arg_of_perigee = self.parse_float(line2[34:42])  # Argument of Perigee (Argumento del perigeo) en grados
        self.mean_anomaly = self.parse_float(line2[43:51])  # Mean Anomaly (Anomalía media) en grados
        self.mean_motion = self.parse_float(line2[52:63])  # Mean Motion (Movimiento medio) en revoluciones por día
        self.revolution_number = self.parse_int(line2[63:68])  # Revolution Number (Número de revolución)

    def parse_float(self, value):
        try:
            return float(value.strip())
        except ValueError:
            return None

    def parse_int(self, value):
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            return None

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name: {self.name}\nSatellite Catalog Number: {self.satellite_catalog_number}\n" \
               f"Classification: {self.classification}\nInternational Designator: {self.international_designator}\n" \
               f"Epoch Year: {self.epoch_year}\nEpoch Day: {self.epoch_day}\n" \
               f"First Derivative of Mean Motion: {self.first_derivative_mean_motion}\n" \
               f"Second Derivative of Mean Motion: {self.second_derivative_mean_motion}\n" \
               f"B* Drag Term: {self.bstar}\nElement Set Number: {self.element_set_number}\n\n" \
               f"Inclination: {self.inclination}\nRAAN: {self.raan}\nEccentricity: {self.eccentricity}\n" \
               f"Argument of Perigee: {self.arg_of_perigee}\nMean Anomaly: {self.mean_anomaly}\n" \
               f"Mean Motion: {self.mean_motion}\nRevolution Number: {self.revolution_number}\n"


def parse_tle_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    satellites = []
    i = 0

    while i < len(lines):
        line1 = lines[i].strip()
        line2 = lines[i + 1].strip()
        line3 = lines[i + 2].strip()

        if line1.startswith('0'):
            # Assuming the first line starts with '0'
            name = line1[2:].strip()
            satellite = Satellite(name, line1, line2, line3)
            satellites.append(satellite)

        i += 3

    return satellites


# Ejemplo de uso
tle_file_path = 'C:/Users/avelascoe/Documents/Indra/BaseTLELEO/Follow/3le20210612.txt'
satellites = parse_tle_file(tle_file_path)

for satellite in satellites:
    print(satellite)


# Datos de conexión a la base de datos
mydb = {
    "user": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "3306",
    "database": "prueba",
}

# Crear la cadena de conexión
connection_string = f'mysql+mysqlconnector://{mydb["user"]}:{mydb["password"]}@{mydb["host"]}:{mydb["port"]}/{mydb["database"]}'

# Crear el motor de la base de datos
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

# Definir la clase de modelo para la tabla satellites
Base = declarative_base()

class SatelliteModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'satellites2'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    satellite_catalog_number = Column(Integer)
    classification = Column(String(1))
    international_designator = Column(String(8))
    epoch_year = Column(Integer)
    epoch_day = Column(Float)
    first_derivative_mean_motion = Column(Float)
    second_derivative_mean_motion = Column(Float)
    bstar = Column(Float)
    element_set_number = Column(Integer)
    inclination = Column(Float)
    raan = Column(Float)
    eccentricity = Column(Float)
    arg_of_perigee = Column(Float)
    mean_anomaly = Column(Float)
    mean_motion = Column(Float)
    revolution_number = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, satellite):
        self.name = satellite.name
        self.satellite_catalog_number = satellite.satellite_catalog_number
        self.classification = satellite.classification
        self.international_designator = satellite.international_designator
        self.epoch_year = satellite.epoch_year
        self.epoch_day = satellite.epoch_day
        self.first_derivative_mean_motion = satellite.first_derivative_mean_motion
        self.second_derivative_mean_motion = satellite.second_derivative_mean_motion
        self.bstar = satellite.bstar
        self.element_set_number = satellite.element_set_number
        self.inclination = satellite.inclination
        self.raan = satellite.raan
        self.eccentricity = satellite.eccentricity
        self.arg_of_perigee = satellite.arg_of_perigee
        self.mean_anomaly = satellite.mean_anomaly
        self.mean_motion = satellite.mean_motion
        self.revolution_number = satellite.revolution_number

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name: {self.name}\nSatellite Catalog Number: {self.satellite_catalog_number}\n" \
               f"Classification: {self.classification}\nInternational Designator: {self.international_designator}\n" \
               f"Epoch Year: {self.epoch_year}\nEpoch Day: {self.epoch_day}\n" \
               f"First Derivative of Mean Motion: {self.first_derivative_mean_motion}\n" \
               f"Second Derivative of Mean Motion: {self.second_derivative_mean_motion}\n" \
               f"B* Drag Term: {self.bstar}\nElement Set Number: {self.element_set_number}\n\n" \
               f"Inclination: {self.inclination}\nRAAN: {self.raan}\nEccentricity: {self.eccentricity}\n" \
               f"Argument of Perigee: {self.arg_of_perigee}\nMean Anomaly: {self.mean_anomaly}\n" \
               f"Mean Motion: {self.mean_motion}\nRevolution Number: {self.revolution_number}\n"


# Crear la tabla si no existe
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Obtener una sesión
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Insertar los datos de los satélites en la tabla
for satellite in satellites:
    satellite_entry = SatelliteModel(satellite)
    session.add(satellite_entry)

# Confirmar los cambios en la base de datos
session.commit()

# Cerrar la sesión
session.close()
```

An example of a TLE file:

```
0 EXPLORER 27

1 01328U 65032A   21163.82915397 -.00000019  00000-0  98086-4 0  9993
2 01328  41.1849 287.6664 0258791 145.7098 216.0662 13.38650203743028


0 EXPLORER 27

1 01328U 65032A   21163.45606331 -.00000026  00000-0  87948-4 0  9990
2 01328  41.1849 289.2622 0258772 143.7661 218.0925 13.38650127742975


0 COSMOS 651

1 07291U 74029A   21163.90434836 -.00000095  00000-0 -32010-5 0  9998
2 07291  64.9715  90.8472 0053392 293.4634  66.0823 13.92930102395772


0 COSMOS 651

1  7291U 74029A   21163.83255253 -.00000095  00000-0 -26747-5 0  9994
2  7291  64.9714  91.0362 0053390 293.4810  66.0649 13.92930106395765
```

Comment: for formatted string, I suggest using delimiter(e.g. space) rather than position.

Comment: Could you give me an example? @Rui

Comment: You can try this with split(), and I will add demo soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an simple example for your test data printed in line 1.

1. First, you can try to parse one line with split(),

```
import string

teststr = "1 01328U 65032A 21163.82915397 -.00000019 00000-0 98086-4 0 9993 2 01328 41.1849 287.6664 0258791 145.7098 216.0662 13.38650203743028"
strlist = teststr.split()
print(strlist)
```

2. Then, you can use 'for' or 'while' to iterate over and convert each value in 'strlist' (this is a list) to the data type you need.

Besides, for your original code, I suggest to try it with just one line data in your txt file. So far, data format are not same even in "0 COSMOS 651" based on your example, e.g. string length of 07291 and 7291.